# Unable to link font awesome file in my working file

Tags: font-awesome

My working file is in this path: programming\neumorphic\neumorphic form\myfile.html
And my all.css file is in this path: programming\css\all.css

I'm trying to link the all.css file with my working file.But result is not showing.

The link path: programming\css\all.css

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the html file to reference the CSS?

Comment: i want to use font awesome icon offline. I have linked my css file.

Answer (score 0):

To use font awesome icons offline download them here https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/ and follow the steps provided.

1. Move font awsome downlaod into direcotry.
2. Then in your css `<head>` tag add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

That's a basic explanation but more information can be found on the above provided link as well.